# Tableau versus Pentaho: What is the difference?

Tags: pentaho, tableau-api

I've been doing some research on Tableau and its functionalities. A friend mentioned I should also look into Pentaho. Can someone give me a run down on the differences between Tableau and Pentaho so I don't need to trawl through all the marketese on each products' website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tableau is only for visual analysis of data. Pentaho does ETL, OLAP (actual cubes with MDX) and static reports, among other things. Tableau is way better at ad-hoc analysis than Pentaho, but Pentaho's ETL tool is one of the best open source tools imo.

My advice, if you're looking to do ETL and create data warehouses, use PDI. The community version has all the features of the enterprise too, so you don't need to bother with a license if you can't get one. For creating reports just download the tableau desktop trial and take it for a spin. Pentaho's ETL tool has a tableau plugin that allows you to create data sources in Tableau's own format.

Comment: How does SSIS fit in this? Should we look into SSIS also as a competitor to Pentaho/Tableau ?